# $\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}\sim\exp(-x^2_k/2)/\sqrt{2\pi npq})$, $x_k=(k-np)/\sqrt{npq}$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $0<p<1$; put $q=1-p$, and
> $$
> \tag{7.3.11}x_{nk}=\frac{k-np}{\sqrt{npq}},\quad0\leq k\leq n\text{.}
> $$
> Clearly $x_{nk}$ depends on both $n$ and $k$, but it will be written as $x_k$ below.
> Let $A$ be an arbitrary but fixed positive constant. Then in the range of $k$ such that
> $$
> \tag{7.3.12}|x_k|\leq A\text{,}
> $$
> we have
> $$
> \tag{7.3.13}\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi npq}}e^{-x_k^2/2}\text{.}
> $$
> The convergence is uniform with respect to $k$ in the range specified above.
> ***Proof.*** We have from (7.3.11)
> $$
> \tag{7.3.14}k=np+\sqrt{npq}x_k\text{,}\quad n-k=nq-\sqrt{npq}x_k\text{.}
> $$
> Hence in the range indicated in (7.3.12),
> $$
> \tag{7.3.15}k\sim np\text{,}\quad n-k\sim nq\text{.}
> $$
> Using Stirling's formula, we may write the left member of (7.3.13) as
> $$\begin{align}
> \tag{7.3.16}
> &\frac{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}p^kq^{n-k}}{\left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k\sqrt{2\pi k}\left(\frac{n-k}{e}\right)^{n-k}\sqrt{2\pi(n-k)}}\\
> &=\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi k(n-k)}}\varphi(n,k)\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi npq}}\varphi(n,k)
> \end{align}$$
> by (7.3.15), where
> $$
> \varphi(n,k)=\left(\frac{np}{k}\right)^k\left(\frac{nq}{n-k}\right)^{n-k}\text{.}
> $$
> Taking logarithms and using the Taylor series, we have by (7.3.14),
> $$\begin{align}
> \log(\frac{np}{k})^k&=k\log(1-\frac{\sqrt{npq}x_k}{k})&=k(-\frac{\sqrt{npq}x_k}{k}-\frac{npqx_k^2}{2k^2}+o(\frac{npqx_k^2}{k^2}))\text{,}\tag{7.3.17}\\
> \log(\frac{nq}{n-k})^{n-k}&=(n-k)\log(1+\frac{\sqrt{npq}x_k}{n-k})&=(n-k)(\frac{\sqrt{npq}x_k}{n-k}-\frac{npqx_k^2}{2(n-k)^2}+o(\frac{npqx_k^2}{(n-k)^2})\text{,}
> \end{align}$$
> provided that
> $$
> \tag{7.3.17'}|\frac{\sqrt{npq}x_k}{k}|<1\quad\text{and}\quad|\frac{\sqrt{npq}x_k}{n-k}|<1\text{.}
> $$
> These conditions are satisfied for sufficiently large values of $n$, in view of (7.3.12) and (7.3.15). Adding the two series expansions, we obtain
> $$
> \log\varphi(n,k)\sim-\frac{n^2pqx_k^2}{2k(n-k)}\text{.}
> $$
> Using (7.3.15) again, we see that
> $$
> \tag{7.3.18}\log\varphi(n,k)\sim-\frac{n^2pqx_k^2}{2npnq}=-\frac{x_k^2}{2}\text{.}
> $$
> In view of (7.3.12), this is equivalent to
> $$
> \tag{*}\varphi(n,k)\sim e^{-x_k^2/2}\text{.}
> $$
> Going back to (7.3.16), we obtain (7.3.13).

I want to ask the equivalence between (7.3.18) and (*). (7.3.18) means that there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converging to $1$ such that
$$
\log\varphi(n,k)=a_n(-\frac{x_k^2}{2})\text{.}
$$
But then
$$
\varphi(n,k)=e^{a_n}\exp(-x_k^2/2)
$$
and $e^{a_n}\rightarrow e$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful $e^{ab} \neq e^ae^b$ (I think that you did the mistake in your last transition).

However if you write $a_n = 1 + b_n$ when $b_n \to 0$, $$\log\phi(n,k) = \left(1+b_n\right) \left(-\frac{x_k^2}{2}\right)$$ after taking the exp you will have,

$$\phi(n,k) = \text{exp}\left(-\frac{x_k^2}{2}\right)\underbrace{\text{exp}\left(-b_n\frac{x_k^2}{2}\right)}_{\to e^0 = 1}$$